# WebRTC connects on local connection, but fails over internet, there is exchange of message

Tags: php, mysql, webrtc

Hope all is well with you,

I have implemented a WebRTC video (only video) conference between two PCs, it works perfectly on locale network (chrome and opera), although it does not work on Firefox. Also, it does not work on Internet on chrome and Firefox. There is an exchange of signalling messages between the two peers (one into my house, other outside my house) but the video does not play on PC outside the house (connected to PC into the house via Internet).

Used the following variables

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection ||  window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
window.RTCIceCandidate = window.RTCIceCandidate || window.mozRTCIceCandidate ||  window.webkitRTCIceCandidate;
window.RTCSessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.webkitRTCSessionDescription;
var peerConnectionConfig = {'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'}, {'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};            
var pcOptions = {optional: [{DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement: false}]
```

I created the peerconnection by calling the function:

```
function createPeerConnection(strdata){
//  strdata contains the descreption receved frome the signalings server
  log('createPeerConnection');
  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig,pcOptions);
  peerConnection.onicecandidate = gotIceCandidate;
  peerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
  peerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = function(ev){ 
     log('============================ '+JSON.stringify(ev));
  }
  data=data.replace(/@/gi, "\\r\\n"); 
  /*
    I use '@' to replace '\r\n'  to avaoid probleme with SQL requests, I 
     replaced all ocurences of '\r\n' by '@' (str.replace(/\\r\\n/gi, "@");
    ), I used the same things for answer, offer and candidates.I use PHP and
     MySQL to store all messages: candidates, offer and answer, 
  */

   var description= JSON.parse(data);
   try{
      log('createPeerConnectionDD');
      peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(description), function() {
          log('set remote description success');
           //offere=true;
          for(i=0;i<msgss.length;i++){
             var data=msgss[i].data.replace(/@/gi, "\\r\\n");
             var candidate= JSON.parse(data);
             log('cand= '+JSON.stringify(candidate));
             peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
          }
          peerConnection.createAnswer(gotDescription, createAnswerError);
       },function(err) {
          log('set remote description fail');
    });
  }catch(e){
    log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is contained in the variable data? Should the rhs in `data=data.replace(/@/gi, "\\r\\n");` contain strdata? Also your flow of events is not clear from the code snippet, you should either provide event logs or a more comprehensive code snippet.

Comment: data is strdat, it is containning the recevied offer from other peer.  In the text I replaced data by strdata in teh argument of the function                  function createPeerConnection(data){
//  strdata contains the descreption receved frome the signalings server

Comment: You seem to be bundling up ice candidates somehow, rather than trickling them. What is that about? That likely explains why it only works on lan (I'm guessing, since you don't show other half of this). Also, what errors do you see in Firefox (web console)?

Comment: Yes of course, I'm bundling messages, especially the offer and the candidate generated by the same peer that generates the offer. That because I'm using XMLHTTPRequest as underlying signaling protocol. 

Now It works well on firefox.

Comment: Hilo dear Jib, addIcecandidate ends with error. The error name is "InvalidStateError", the message is: "Cannot add ICE candidate in statehave-local_offer".